# Json structure is returned empty, without property names and values when using Newtonsoft JsonConvert in FB C# client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk, json.net, jsonserializer, jsonresult

I'm working on asp.net mvc 4 application which uses Facebook C# SDK (6.0.10.0) and Newtonsoft.Json (4.5.0.0).

Request with FacebookClient returns expando object:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetFbData(string path = "me"){
    var expando = this.fb.Get(path);

    return Json(expando);
}
```

Returned Json looks like:

```
[{"Key":"id","Value":"100000xxxxxxxx"},{"Key":"name","Value":"John Doe"} ... ]
```

I want to return it in format `{id:100000xxxxxxx, name:"John Doe", ... }` so I added this to the code which creates my fb client:

```
fb.SetJsonSerializers(JsonConvert.SerializeObject,
                      JsonConvert.DeserializeObject);
```

Same code from above now returns:

```
[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[[[]],[[]]]],[[[[]],[[]]]],[[]],[[]],[[[[[[[]],[[]]...]
```

I can get desired result with:

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Expando));
```

This returns proper Json, but Content-Type is `text/html; charset=utf-8`, and I'm wondering how I can return the desired format as JsonResult without manually setting response headers etc, I just want to change default serialization behavior without re-implementing serializer etc.

There must be something simple that is done with **single line of code** to change this behavior, and I'm hoping that someone already found it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but you almost had it.  Content takes a second parameter that is the content type, so if you change it to be

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Expando), "application/json");
```

it should work as expected

Comment: Yes, that is how I "solved" it, but I did not consider it a "real" solution because I wanted to be able to return .net JsonResult.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may see this in the future, when I encountered this same bug the root cause was that the  Json serialization was failing because there was no explicit type set on my result object.

I.e. inside my Controller get

`return Json(res.Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` where `res.Data` was of type `object Result<object>.Data` instead of a class.